# List all available public images with Gcloud APIs

Tags: api, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I was wondering if there is an equivalent to this Gcloud SDK command just using the Gcloud APIs:

```
gcloud compute images list
```

I have already tried with the images.list() endpoint, but I'm aware this retrieves your custom images, not the public ones. I need the whole list of all the publicly available images.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the 'compute.images.list' API method only retrieves custom images, to get a list of public images you have to request the specific image project such as `centos-cloud` or `debian-cloud`, thus making multiple call to  each public image project. You can use the code examples [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/images/list#examples) and add an iteration to retrieve the public images as a workaround. There's a public feature request for this, you can follow it through this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/64718267).

Comment: Update: according to the GCP docs you can now list public images https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#list_of_public_images_available_on